# Use constants or no for expectations in tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

For example, we have some big page that we testing, and for test we have big mock.
And one of our expectations - check value of product price.
It can be done like:

```
expect(price).toBe(20);
```

Or, we can use value directly from mock:

```
expect(price).toBe(orderMock.data.user.order.price);
```

Or define additional variable like:

```
const expectedPrice = orderMock.data.user.order.price;
expect(price).toBe(expectedPrice);
```

Which way will be preferrable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe both ways are ok in your scenario, however I would declare const mostly when I have multiple attributes, in order to avoid repeat `orderMock.data.user.order` too many.

Sometimes you can use object destructuring as well, when you have more attributes:

```js
const { price:expectedPrice, otherAttribute } = orderMock.data.user.order;
expect(price).toBe(expectedPrice);
expect(otherValue).toBe(otherAttribute);
```

*Just keep in mind if you do something similar with methods [you may lose your bind.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)*

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate second way a lot more, cause its re-useable and it's says about it self - variable names are like descriptions

PS: In my opinion you should use var instead of const cause many older browsers dont fully support const https://caniuse.com/?search=const
If im right const is full supported since ECMA 6